# How do I increase the performance of Dataframe.write?

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a PySpark dataframe to AWS Redshift.
I am using `postActions` parameters for deletion.

But this snippet is taking a lot of time to complete.

Is there a way to improve the `DATAFRAME.write` speed ?

````py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, types

EXTRACOPYOPTIONS = "TRUNCATECOLUMNS EMPTYASNULL BLANKSASNULL TRIMBLANKS ACCEPTANYDATE TIMEFORMAT 'auto' MAXERROR 0 DATEFORMAT 'auto'"
postActions = f"""
        DELETE FROM {MASTER_TABLE} USING {staging} WHERE {MASTER_TABLE}.{key_to_update} = {staging}.{key_to_update};
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {staging}
    """
DATAFRAME.write \
        .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
        .option("url",  REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL) \
        .option("dbtable", staging) \
        .option("extracopyoptions", EXTRACOPYOPTIONS) \
        .option("postactions", postActions) \
        .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
        .option("tempdir", "s3a://"+S3_BUCKET+"/tempdir") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()

DATAFRAME.write \
        .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
        .option("url",  REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL) \
        .option("dbtable", MASTER_TABLE) \
        .option("extracopyoptions", EXTRACOPYOPTIONS) \
        .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
        .option("tempdir", "s3a://"+S3_BUCKET+"/tempdir") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()```
````

Comment: Using 'auto' for date/time formats is a bad idea.  You have no idea if Redshift if picking the correct format.  Sometimes it goes wrong.

Comment: Would it affect write performance, assuming the time format is correctly specified source `DATAFRAME`

Comment: Write is an action in spark. Since you're writing it twice, the entire DAG is computed twice by spark. Can you look into the Spark History Server and look in the spark stages? When we have multiple actions on the same DF, it is preferable to cache the df using df.cache().

Comment: i will look into that. But is it recommended to use `pyspark` just to write to `s3` , then use redshift `copy` command to transfer to `redshift`. Would that be faster than the above mentioned method

Answer (score 1):

On the Redshift side, it's already running a COPY from S3 on your behalf. So I expect you will be able to get a speed increase by adding two more options to your EXTRACOPYOPTIONS

```
COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF
```

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html) those options will stop Redshift doing the compression evaluation and gathering the statistics.

Potentially most beneficial if

- the table is wide (many columns) because those two optimizations are done per column
- you don't need the statistics (e.g. you will be fully scanning the table later)
- you are confident that you have already chosen the best [compression encodings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Compression_encodings.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look into it. Also the doc u linked here says `Running COPY with the NOLOAD parameter is much faster than loading the data` . Would you recommend that ?

Comment: NOLOAD checks the validity of the data file without actually loading the data, so it will probably be fast, but it won't actually load anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a single Dataframe.write operation to write the data first into stage table and then use postactions option to write the data into main table.
2. You can use overwrite option rather than append which will be more efficient
3. If you use overwrite mode, Dataframe.write option might change the schema of the table its going to write the data, so you should be sure about the column datatypes or you have to enforce the schema while reading the data
4. Sparks dataframe.write option copy the dataframe into temp directory and convert it to avro format and then use copy command of redshift. If you have the expected data already available in s3,  dataframe.write might be less efficient when compared to using copy command on s3 path directly.

   ```
          postActions = f"""
            DELETE FROM {MASTER_TABLE} USING {staging} WHERE {MASTER_TABLE}.{key_to_update}= {staging}.{key_to_update};
            INSERT INTO {MASTER_TABLE} SELECT * FROM  {staging};  
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {staging};"""            
         DATAFRAME.write \
            .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
            .option("url",  REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL) \
            .option("dbtable", staging) \
            .option("extracopyoptions", EXTRACOPYOPTIONS) \
            .option("postactions", postActions) \
            .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
            .option("tempdir", "s3a://"+S3_BUCKET+"/tempdir") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .save()
   ```